# Brute Forcing DVWA with Hydra

Tags: hydra, dvwa

I am attempting to brute-force 'DVWA/vulnerabilities/brute/' with Hydra, rockyou.txt password list.
I tried using this command:

```
hydra 127.0.0.1 -V -l admin -P rockyou.txt http-get-form "/DVWA/vulnerabilities/brute/:username=^USER^&password=^PASS^&Login=Login:F=Username and/or password incorrect.:H=Cookie: security=low; PHPSESSID=0tp8jmqci1c8qblpgocgkuck0p"
```

And the output of this is:

```
[80][http-get-form] host: localhost   login: admin   password: iloveyou
[80][http-get-form] host: localhost   login: admin   password: princess
[80][http-get-form] host: localhost   login: admin   password: 1234567
[80][http-get-form] host: localhost   login: admin   password: 123456
[80][http-get-form] host: localhost   login: admin   password: 12345
[80][http-get-form] host: localhost   login: admin   password: 123456789
[80][http-get-form] host: localhost   login: admin   password: password
[80][http-get-form] host: localhost   login: admin   password: 12345678
[80][http-get-form] host: localhost   login: admin   password: nicole
[80][http-get-form] host: localhost   login: admin   password: rockyou
[80][http-get-form] host: localhost   login: admin   password: abc123
[80][http-get-form] host: localhost   login: admin   password: daniel
[80][http-get-form] host: localhost   login: admin   password: babygirl
[80][http-get-form] host: localhost   login: admin   password: monkey
[80][http-get-form] host: localhost   login: admin   password: lovely
[80][http-get-form] host: localhost   login: admin   password: jessica
1 of 1 target successfully completed, 16 valid passwords found
```

16 passwords that doesn't even work...
I tried changing '127.0.0.1' with 'localhost', changing Cookie...

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

Check if DVWA application is set up correctly. For instance, call `http://localhost/index.php` or `http://localhost/about.php`. If the application is set up correctly, you will see corresponding text from PHP. Otherwise you will see errors like 500 or 502. The reasons can be for instance incorrect integration of web server with PHP, or incorrect connection of DVWA to database.

In case application is set up incorrectly, the response will not contain the expected error message. Hydra will consider this as *success*, no matter what passwords you will provide.

Comment: I'm trying to brute force "DWVA/vulnerabilities/brute", not "/DVWA/login.php". If I try to enter wrong credentials on "DWVA/vulnerabilities/brute", I get "Username and/or password incorrect."

Comment: @Dzomba: See the updated answer.

Comment: When I try to load '.../about.php' or '.../index.php', I get "The requested URL was not found on this server.". How can I fix this ?

Comment: @Dzomba: Install web server like Apache or Nginx. Install PHP. Integrate web server with PHP. Configure DVWA so that it is works with web server and PHP. DVWA requires also MySQL or PostgreSQL, so configure DVWA correspondingly.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you're running hydra from Kali, right? I think there is a bug with the current version, try to install hydra back again from here:
https://github.com/vanhauser-thc/thc-hydra

Comment: Yes, I am. I'll try this ASAP...

Comment: @Giorgio Piras: See the comment of the author: The requests return "The requested URL was not found on this server." This means, DVWA is not set up correctly. It has nothing to do with Hydra.