# All passwords valid hydra

Tags: hydra, dvwa

I was trying hydra out on DVWA login page, but it returned all 7 passwords correct, while only one was correct.

Here is the command:

```
hydra -l admin -P passlist.txt -V -I 192.168.70.130 http-post-form "/login.php:username=^USER^&password=^PASS^&Login=Login:Login failed"
```

Here is what it returns:

```
Hydra (https://github.com/vanhauser-thc/thc-hydra) starting at 2021-09-11 13:21:22
[DATA] max 7 tasks per 1 server, overall 7 tasks, 7 login tries (l:1/p:7), ~1 try per task
[DATA] attacking http-post-form://192.168.70.130:80/login.php:username=^USER^&password=^PASS^&Login=Login:Login failed
[ATTEMPT] target 192.168.70.130 - login "admin" - pass "p@ssw0rd" - 1 of 7 [child 0] (0/0)
[ATTEMPT] target 192.168.70.130 - login "admin" - pass "mindukas1263" - 2 of 7 [child 1] (0/0)
[ATTEMPT] target 192.168.70.130 - login "admin" - pass "kali" - 3 of 7 [child 2] (0/0)
[ATTEMPT] target 192.168.70.130 - login "admin" - pass "password" - 4 of 7 [child 3] (0/0)
[ATTEMPT] target 192.168.70.130 - login "admin" - pass "KasTauYra" - 5 of 7 [child 4] (0/0)
[ATTEMPT] target 192.168.70.130 - login "admin" - pass "tunelis" - 6 of 7 [child 5] (0/0)
[ATTEMPT] target 192.168.70.130 - login "admin" - pass "minduxas" - 7 of 7 [child 6] (0/0)
[80][http-post-form] host: 192.168.70.130   login: admin   password: p@ssw0rd
[80][http-post-form] host: 192.168.70.130   login: admin   password: mindukas1263
[80][http-post-form] host: 192.168.70.130   login: admin   password: kali
[80][http-post-form] host: 192.168.70.130   login: admin   password: password
[80][http-post-form] host: 192.168.70.130   login: admin   password: KasTauYra
[80][http-post-form] host: 192.168.70.130   login: admin   password: tunelis
[80][http-post-form] host: 192.168.70.130   login: admin   password: minduxas
1 of 1 target successfully completed, 7 valid passwords found
Hydra (https://github.com/vanhauser-thc/thc-hydra) finished at 2021-09-11 13:21:22
```

I've looked everywhere, but I can't find a solution.

Comment: Hi you should try to use wfuzz instead of hydra for http post form

Comment: Please look through the `hydra` posts here. And the hydra documentation. You are not using the correct syntax for telling hydra what failure looks like. So it thinks that all are succeeding...

Comment: Can you send a specific link to what that syntax is? Also if it's `F=failure here` than it's not the case, I have tried it before.

Comment: Does these answer your question: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/195219/brute-forcing-dvwa-login-page-with-hydra or https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/242830/brute-forcing-dvwa-with-hydra

Comment: I keep forgetting that my knowledge of hydra is old. Your syntax is fine. But the problem is the same: hydra thinks that the password passed the test you gave it. You need to figure out why. We've had the same question asked here over the years.

Comment: Well I do understand the problem, but I can't find a solution. I am too dumb to find it by myself and if no one answered this question for years as you said, well I'm screwed.

Comment: Are you sure that "Login failed" is correct? The other questions I liked include changingthat and other parameters. Have you tried them?

Comment: I tried only doing failed, still didn't work.